# NotificationListenerService in androidTv

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-tv

I am working on an android app which will run in androidTv(currently i am using MiBox for my testing purposes)
The requirement is like i need capture the number active notifications received by the android OS and show it somewhere in the APP.

## **Service which i've written:**

```
package org.libsdl.app;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.Notification.Action;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Message;
import android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService;
import android.service.notification.StatusBarNotification;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.haxe.lime.HaxeObject;

public class AndroidNotificationListener extends NotificationListenerService {

    private static final int EVENT_UPDATE_CURRENT_NOS = 0;
    public static List<StatusBarNotification[]> mCurrentNotifications = new                 
    ArrayList<StatusBarNotification[]>();
    public static int mActiveNotificationsCount = 0;
    public static StatusBarNotification mPostedNotification;
    public static StatusBarNotification mRemovedNotification;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return super.onBind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent mIntent) {
        return super.onUnbind(mIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        updateCurrentNotifications();
        mPostedNotification = sbn;

        // Get the text from notification
        // CharSequence notificationText = sbn.getNotification().extras.getCharSequence(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT);

        // Show a toast with your Notification Text
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), notificationText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        updateCurrentNotifications();
        mRemovedNotification = sbn;
    }

    public void onListenerConnected() {
    // Add some prints here to check if our service is connected to OS or not?
    }

    private void updateCurrentNotifications() {
        try {
            StatusBarNotification[] activeNos = getActiveNotifications();
            if (mCurrentNotifications.size() == 0) {
                mCurrentNotifications.add(null);
            }
            mCurrentNotifications.set(0, activeNos);
            mActiveNotificationsCount = activeNos.length;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Anil : AndroidNotificationListener  : Should not be here!!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }

     public static StatusBarNotification[] getCurrentNotifications() {
        if (mCurrentNotifications.size() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        return mCurrentNotifications.get(0);
    }
    }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml part is:**

```
<service
android:name="org.libsdl.app.AndroidNotificationListener"
android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE"
android:enabled="true" >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
</intent-filter>
</service>
```

Same service is working for my phone but in my androidTv(MiBox) it is not working.
and as in phone we have settings from where we can enable/disable our app to receive notifications the same option is not available in MiBox.
My MiBox has Android M and my phone has Android N. am i missing something which i should know before running this service in Android service?
So my question is about why this service is not working in androidTv?
any help on this will be much appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

I've found the reason why my dummy app worked on my phone and did not work on miBox.
On my phone, when i installed the dummy app it asked for permission to receive the notification and when i gave the permission it started to receive permission.
On miBox, we do not have any way to give permission to our app to receive notification.
In short, the app was not able to receive the notification on miBox because the app did not have the permission because or listener/app to receive the notification was attached.

and there are no way we can attach the listener for notification to our app in android tvs. But we can do it only when the app is signed as a system app.

Answer (score 0):

```
        if (verifyNotificationPermission()) {
            //You have the permission to listen to the System Notification
        } else {
             //can ask for permission if it not yet granted
            // show dialog why you need this permission and if
            // user is ok with the permission then call 
            //openNotificationPermissionPanel
        }
        
        fun openNotificationPermissionPanel(){
          //Below code will open side panel and will show list of apps and there is a way to unable and disable the Permission 
        startActivity(new Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS"));
        }
    
    // fun to check if your launcher app has permission or not 
    fun verifyNotificationPermission(): Boolean? {
            val theList = Settings.Secure.getString(
                activity.getContentResolver(),
                "enabled_notification_listeners"
            )
            val theListList = theList.split(":").toTypedArray()
            val me = ComponentName(activity, NotificationService::class.java).flattenToString()
            for (next in theListList) {
                if (me == next) {
                    return true
                }
            }
            return false
        }
```

Comment: Have u added NotificationChannel ?

Comment: @GauravMandlik we don't need to as we are listening to the notification not sending

Comment: It will not work for the question that I've asked. Check the reason at https://stackoverflow.com/a/55096856/8664445